# Separation variable for the Laplace equation: why ther is no image part of the cylindar coordinate? [Classical Electrodynamics - Jackson]

Tags: physics, laplacian

[Classical Electrodynamics Third Edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Classical+Electrodynamics%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471309321#description-section) solves the Laplace equation on spherical coordinate and cylindrical coordinate. I wonder why the image part of the general solution of the azimuthal angle is missing in the cylindrical coordinate.

### Spherical coordinates

Here is the process to derive the solution on spherical coordinates in the book.

Assume the target function.

$$\Phi = \frac{U(r)}{r}P(\theta)Q(\phi)$$

And get these equations.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{Q}\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial\phi^2} &= -m^2 \\
\frac{r^2}{U}\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial r^2} &= l(l+1) \\
\frac{1}{P\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left( \sin\theta \frac{\partial P}{\partial\theta} \right) -\frac{m^2}{\sin^2\theta} &= - l(l+1)
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
Q &= e^{\pm im \phi} = \cos(m\phi) \pm \sin(m\phi) \\
U &= Ar^{l + 1} + Br^{-l} \\
P &= P^m_l
\end{align*}$$

### Cylindrical coordinate

$$\Phi = R(r)Q(\phi)Z(z)$$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{Z}\frac{d^2 Z}{dz^2} &= k^2 \\
\frac{1}{Q}\frac{d^2Q}{d \phi^2} &= -\nu^2 \\
\frac{1}{R}\left[ \frac{d^2R}{d\rho^2} + \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dR}{d\rho} \right] &= \frac{\nu^2}{\rho^2} - k^2
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
Z(z) &= e^{\pm kz} = \sinh kz \\
Q(\phi) &= e^{\pm i\nu \phi} = A \sin m\phi + B \cos m\phi \\
R(\rho) &= CJ_\nu(k\rho) + DN_\nu(k\rho) \\
\end{align*}$$

[image]

**Why there is no image part of $Q$ in the solution of the cylindrical one compared to the spherical one?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'image part'?

Comment: The image part I meant is $i\sin m\phi$

Comment: I presume the first expression you list has a typo (either you or Jackson) since $e^{im\phi}=\cos(m\phi)+i\sin(m\phi)$. In the spherical case, writing the $i$ next to $\sin$ is not necessary, because there is already an arbitrary constant $A$ next to it, and $iA$ is still an arbitrary constant